# OracleDB Fetch from Select when handling output CLOB Type cause Python crash

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-oracledb

I have been using SQLAlchemy with OracleDB as driver to build my applications.

I observed one of the process being killed unexpectedly while being inside a try except Exception block.

And after trial and error, I found the reason to be the handler being used to read data from CLOB and BLOB to string.

```
def output_type_handler(cursor, metadata):
    if metadata.type_code is oracledb.DB_TYPE_CLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if metadata.type_code is oracledb.DB_TYPE_BLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG_RAW, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if metadata.type_code is oracledb.DB_TYPE_NCLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG_NVARCHAR, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
```

I tried using OracleDB alone without SqlAlchemy and successfully fetched the data and read the CLOB with read().

However, after I enabled the outputtypehandler, even fetchone() cause Jupyter to crash with ExitCode: 3221225477.

I have tried other settings like oracledb.defaults.fetch_lobs = False and it also caused the same problem.

Are there any configs I can use with SQLAlchemy to fix this?

Edit: I found the problem happen when I access a table with multiple CLOB columns across DBLink. It works fine without DBLink.

- DB Version: 19.6c
- Client Version: 21c
- Python: 3.9.5
- oracledb: 1.4.2
- SQLAlchemy: 2.0.23
- Connection Type: Thick Mode

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTOMAIL_JOB_LIST (
ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1,
ID_DEFINITION NUMBER,
SERVICE_GROUP VARCHAR2 (100 Char),
SUBJECT VARCHAR2 (300 Char),
EMAIL_CONTENT CLOB,
ATTACHMENT CLOB,
SEND_TO CLOB,
SEND_CC CLOB,
SEND_BCC CLOB,
STATUS NUMBER(2) DEFAULT 0,
CREATE_DATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
SEND_DATE DATE DEFAULT NULL,
OWNER_EMAIL VARCHAR2(200 CHAR))
```

The table is storing emails to send. The columns attachment, send_to, send_cc, and send_bcc usually are just a few email/filepath. The problem came from EMAIL_CONTENT column that store the entire html of the email, which could contain tables.

Fetching them all but EMAIL_CONTENT and then EMAIL_CONTENT alone is fine, but it will cause problem when SELECT *

Sample Code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine("", connect_args = {
                                "encoding": "UTF-16",
                                "nencoding": "UTF-16"
                            },
                        thick_mode = True,
                        pool_pre_ping = True,
                        echo_pool = True,
                        pool_size = 1)

query = """
            SELECT *
            FROM AUTOMAIL_JOB_LIST@DBLINK
        """

df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

OracleDB-Python Version:

```
import oracledb
import pandas as pd
oracledb.init_oracle_client()

def output_type_handler(cursor, metadata):
    if metadata.type_code is oracledb.DB_TYPE_CLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if metadata.type_code is oracledb.DB_TYPE_BLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG_RAW, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if metadata.type_code is oracledb.DB_TYPE_NCLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG_NVARCHAR, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

query = """
            SELECT *
            FROM AUTOMAIL_JOB_LIST@DBLINK
        """

oracle_connection_string = oracledb.makedsn(oracle_host, oracle_port, service_name = oracle_service_name)
oracle_connection = oracledb.connect(user = oracle_username, password = oracle_password, dsn = oracle_connection_string, encoding = "UTF-16", nencoding = "UTF-16")
oracle_connection.outputtypehandler = output_type_handler

df = pd.read_sql(query, oracle_connection)

# cursor = oracle_connection.cursor()
# cursor.execute(query)
# row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Jupyter Notebook to reproduce the problem
https://github.com/TuanDang293/BugReproduce/blob/main/Code.ipynb

Comment: What versions of the components? Can you share a runnable test case with sample data?  Why do you need these settings in SQLAlchemy - isn't [auto_convert_lobs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/oracle.html#cx-oracle-lob) already True?

Comment: @ChristopherJones Automatically converting lobs to string is causing this problem. Fetching LOB Locators and then read() manually seems to be fine in OracleDB-Python. I will try to create a sample.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I have edited the question and add in more information, please see the end of the question.

Comment: We will need more information such as the versions of the DB, client, driver, whether thick mode is used etc.  Does it reproduce if you run a command line script without Jupyter? We will also need some kind of testcase that is bigger than the snippet you posted.

Comment: @ChristopherJones DB Version is 19.6c. I'm using Client Version 21c on Thick Mode with the newest version of OracleDB-Python/SqlAlchemy. I ran it on both Jupyter and as a script. In Jupyter, it crashed the kernel and exited with code 3221225477 while running as a script it will kill python.exe outright even inside try except block. I will add more information to the question.

Comment: Are you able to try it with thin mode? (comment out the call to init_oracle_client()) It may help by presenting a different response that may poinpoint the source of the issue.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga Hi, sorry for the late reply. I have tried to setup a dblink at home but couldn't so I had to wait until I got on my company computer again. I have found out why I didn't use Thin mode in the first place, the DBs has sec_case_sensitive_logon set to False. As I am not familiar with this settings, I afraid I won't be able to submit a change request to change this setting.

Comment: Understood. We'll continue to see if we can find a way to replicate the issue in house.